How to properly organise a backend API structure in ColdFusion (CF9)
I have written a very basic API for my client using ColdFusion.
Currently I have endpoints with cfm files for each endpoint at that location.

For example:
/api/settings/post-external-content/
The file at that location has this response:
<cfset fileName = toString(getHttpRequestData().content)>
<cfset baseURL = 'https://longurl.com'>
<cfset fileString = deserializeJSON(fileName)>

<!--- Double-check to make sure we have a request body. --->
<cfif len(fileString.fileName)>
     <cfx_http5 
        out='httpResponse'
        method='get'
        url='#baseURL#/#fileString.fileName#'
        ssl='5'
        timeout='10000'
    />
    <cfset data = StructNew()>  
    <cfset body = httpResponse>
    <cfset data['body'] = body>
    <cfset data['status'] = 200>
    <cfoutput>#serializeJSON(data)#</cfoutput>
<cfelse>
    <cfset data = StructNew()>
    <cfset body = 'Sorry, something went wrong'>
    <cfset data['body'] = body>
    <cfset data['status'] = 503>
    <cfoutput>#serializeJSON(data)#</cfoutput>
</cfif>

So in the FE I send a post request to the same endpoint.
const url = '/api/settings/post-external-content/';
const options = {
   method: 'POST',
   headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   body: JSON.stringify(file)
};
fetch(url, options)
   .then((response) => response.json())
   .then((data) => {
      if (data.status === 200) {
         updateContent(data.body);
      } else {
         console.log(`Uh oh. Status: ${data.status}`);
   }
   ...

In Express/Node you can just write listeners in your root app.js (or import them as modules) and they will listen to calls to/from the endpoints. This is the bit I am not sure how to do in CF.
For example:
app.post('/api/someendpoint', (req, res) => {
    const data = { someJSONObject };
    const query = {
      body: {
        data: data
      }
    }
    res.send(query);
  });
});

app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
  res.send(data);
});

As we have CF9 on the server I don't have access to cfhttp (we use a library called cfx_http5 but I think the principles are very similar).
I have seen talk of using a single cfc file and handle all of the api calls there, centrally, but I haven't worked with cfc's much (outside of the main Application.cfc). I am wondering if that would be a better and cleaner approach, it seems a bit daft to have to have files in those locations if the server can listen to the endpoints.
I hope this isn't too vague.  I would appreciate any input.
EDIT
So I decided to try and write a cfc to see how complex it was and if I could port my code over easily enough.
So now I have a single API.cfc which looks like this:
<!--- API functions --->
<cfcomponent>

    <cfset method = #CGI.REQUEST_METHOD#>

    <!--- create a file path --->
    <cfset filePath = '../../../data'>

    <!--- Try and prevent direct access to the cfc --->
    <cfif not structKeyExists(url, 'method')>
        <cfset url.method = 'returnVoid'>
    </cfif>

    <!--- getResponse data for layout --->
    <cffunction name='getResponse' access='remote' output='yes' returntype='string' returnformat='plain'>
   ... 
       <!--- postResponse for sending layout data --->
    <cffunction name='postResponse' access='remote' output='yes' returntype='string'>
   ...
       <!--- postExternalContent response to get html content from remote URL --->
    <cffunction  name='postExternalContent' access='remote' output='yes' returntype='string' returnformat='plain'>
        <cfset content = toString(getHttpRequestData().content)>
   ...
   </cfcomponent>

And then in the frontend config all I have had to do is update my endpoints:
const global = {
    apiController: '/api/API.cfc',
}

global.apiGetURL = `${global.apiController}?method=getResponse`;
global.apiPostURL = `${global.apiController}?method=postResponse`;
global.apiPostExternalContentURL = `${global.apiController}?method=postExternalContent`;

Everything seems to work the same, I am assuming this is a cleaner way to do this, the only thing now is that instead of a nice clean looking endpoint like:
/api/settings/post-external-content/
It's not pointing to:
/api/API.cfc?method=getResponse
I guess it's fine. I only have 3 functions but I've worked on apps in other organisations where there were 20 endpoints, so I don't know how you split the cfc down (or would you have to make separate ones for different endpoints).
Anyway some of this is conjecture, but still would like to hear any feedback.
